# TreeView Delphi com link BD

Tags: delphi, treeview

Tenho criado um `Treeview` com os dados que estão em uma tabela no BD, e tem um campo que contém o nome no formulário.
Como fazer para dar um `ShowModal` no evento `OnClick` do `Treeview` pegando o nome do formulário que está no campo da tabela?

Segue o código:

```
procedure CriaFormpeloNome(const FrmNome : string);
var
  FrmClass : TFormClass;
  Frm : TForm;
begin

  try
    FrmClass := TFormClass(FindClass(FrmNome));
    Frm      := FrmClass.Create(application);
  except
    //não achou a classe
    showmessage('Não achou a classe');
  end;
end;


procedure TFormFrontend.TreeView2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
Form2 : string;
begin
zmenu.SQL.Clear;
zmenu.SQL.Add('Select * from tab_menu');
zmenu.SQL.Add('WHERE id =:id');
zmenu.Params.ParamByName('id').value:= TreeView2.Selected.AbsoluteIndex;
zmenu.Open;
Form2:= zmenuarquivo.AsString;
Form2 := concat('T',Form2);
CriaFormpeloNome(Form2);
end;
```

Comment: Inclua seu código, fica mais fácil de alguém te ajudar ;)

Answer (score 0):

A unica coisa que vejo faltar no seu código é que para usar o FindClass é necessário chamar o RegisterClass previamente. Diria que tem de inicialmente chamar o RegisterClass para todas as classes de forms que deseja abrir e depois o codigo que tem funciona.

Este pequeno exemplo funciona:

```
procedure CriaFormpeloNome(const FrmNome : string);
var
   FrmClass : TFormClass;
   Frm : TForm;
begin
   try
      FrmClass := TFormClass(FindClass(FrmNome));
      Frm      := FrmClass.Create(application);
      if Frm<>nil then
        frm.ShowModal;
   except
     //não achou a classe
     showmessage('Nao Achou a classe');
   end;
end;

procedure TForm5.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RegisterClass(TForm5);
  CriaFormpeloNome('TForm5');
end;
```

Comment: OK deu certo, obrigado amigo